# Aligning dashed lines with SLD

Tags: sld

I would like to create a dashed line with a repeated symbol like below, but with the dashed lines aligned between the symbols. How shall I think, right now I'm just guessing?

[image]

Here is my current SLD:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <ogc:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
   <ogc:NamedLayer>
     <ogc:Name>Aerodrome</ogc:Name>
        <ogc:UserStyle>
           <ogc:Name>Aerodrome</ogc:Name>
           <ogc:FeatureTypeStyle>
              <ogc:Name>name</ogc:Name>
              <ogc:Rule>
                 <ogc:Title>A green dashed line with symbols</ogc:Title>
                 <ogc:LineSymbolizer>
                    <ogc:Stroke>
                       <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke">#73ed5d</ogc:CssParameter>
                       <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3.26</ogc:CssParameter>
                       <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</ogc:CssParameter>
                       <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</ogc:CssParameter>
                       <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">19 39</ogc:CssParameter>
                    </ogc:Stroke>
                 </ogc:LineSymbolizer>
                 <ogc:LineSymbolizer>
                    <ogc:Stroke>
                       <ogc:GraphicStroke>
                          <ogc:Graphic>
                             <ogc:ExternalGraphic>
                                <ogc:OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="aerodrome.svg?fill=#FF4444&amp;fill-opacity=1.0&amp;outline=#FF4444&amp;outline-opacity=1.0&amp;outline-width=0.0"/>
                                <ogc:Format>image/svg+xml</ogc:Format>
                                <ogc:Fill>
                                   <ogc:CssParameter name="fill">#0000FF</ogc:CssParameter>
                                   <ogc:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</ogc:CssParameter>
                                </ogc:Fill>
                                 <ogc:Stroke>
                                   <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</ogc:CssParameter>
                                   <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</ogc:CssParameter>
                                   <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">21 35</ogc:CssParameter>
                                </ogc:Stroke>
                             </ogc:ExternalGraphic>
                             <Size>25</Size>
                          </ogc:Graphic>
                       </ogc:GraphicStroke>
                    </ogc:Stroke>
                 </ogc:LineSymbolizer>
              </ogc:Rule>
           </ogc:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </ogc:UserStyle>
     </ogc:NamedLayer>
  </ogc:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: I've tried to make the title a bit more meaningful but I'm not sure what you mean by "with the dashed lines aligned". Could you draw some example? Oh, do you want the symbols to appear exactly in the gaps in the dashed line?

Comment: Yes, exactly in middle of the gaps.

Comment: Create a dash array for the line: <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">20 40</ogc:CssParameter>
Create the same dash array for the symbol, then offset the symbol dash array:                                   <ogc:CssParameter name="stroke-dashoffset">30</ogc:CssParameter>

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of this in the [SLD Cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/lines.html#alternating-symbols-with-dash-offsets). I think the key trick is to make the two dasharrays add up to the same length and then to offset the start of the lines by half that length.

I would experiment with your SLD but it's in the wrong namespace.